# regular expression for amount enclosed

Tags: regex

This regular expression

```
/^\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

limits the user to only 6 digits.

1. How to make this regex work to allow any number of digits(no max limit)
2. How to make this regex optional

Comment: What do you mean by "optional"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: if amount entered then validate otherwise no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just mean any number of digits followed by any single character followed by 2 digits, then use:

```
/^\d+(?:.\d{0,2})?$/
```

If 0 is ok, then:

```
/^\d*(?:.\d{0,2})?$/
```

I think you actually are trying to find money values (dollar and cents) which would likely be this instead:

```
/^\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

Comment: @ridgerunner, whoops, typo...  meant $

Comment: @Lucas: /^\d*(?:.\d{0,2})?$/   /^\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/
what is the difference btw the two regex? can u provide me an example

Comment: @user1078081, there is a _backslash_ before the `.` in the middle.  `.` means any character, but if you are using this to look for things like money, then you probably meant the literal `.` which is why I escaped it with the _backslash_.

Comment: @user1078081, dont forget to mark your answer when you are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex limits it to 1-6 digits, followed by an optional 0-2 decimals.

To remove the limit, remove the `{1,6}` and replace with `+` and to make it optional, wrap in `(...)?`:

```
/(^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$)?/
```

This make the input, if provided, still require at least 1 digit before the decimal place.

Comment: I'll point out that you are assuming that the value, if provided, contains only digits or . .  Your expression allows the value 'x' to match.

Answer (score 1):

To make the first part match one or more digits, you can change it to `/^\d+(?:.\d{0,2})?$/`.

It's a bit confusing what you mean by 'optional', so I'm not sure what to suggest there.